# which statement is correct?

Tags: ring-theory

$S$ is the power set of $\Bbb Z$. Define two binary operations: $+$ (the symmetric difference set which means $A+B=(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)$ and $*$ (the intersection of two sets $A*B=A\cap B$, which form a ring,

1. $*$ has a unit
2. if $A*B$ is an empty set, $A$ or $B$ is empty.
3. Every element's inverse in $S$ is itself.

Please explain this question and help me. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? If you are completely stuck, try using a small set, like $\lbrace 1, 2 \rbrace$ to see if you can get some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit is the multiplicative identity, so (1) is the claim that there is some subset $U$ of $\Bbb Z$ such that $U*A=A$ for every $A\in S$. Since $*$ is just intersection, this means that $U\cap A=A$ for every $A\subseteq\Bbb Z$. There’s exactly one subset of $\Bbb Z$ with that property; what is it?

For (2), you should again just translate $*$ into $\cap$: if $A\cap B=\varnothing$, does it follow that at least one of $A$ and $B$ is $\varnothing$? To ask the same question a little differently, is it **necessarily** true that if $A\ne\varnothing\ne B$, then $A\cap B\ne\varnothing$?

Since this is a ring, we’ve no reason to expect that it has multiplicative inverses, so *inverse* here must mean *additive inverse*: the claim is that for any $A\in S$, $A+A$ is the additive identity. Now $A+A=(A\cup A)\setminus(A\cap A)=A\setminus A=\varnothing$ no matter what $A$ is, so at least it’s true that $A+A$ is always the same member of $S$, namely, $\varnothing$. Is $\varnothing$ is the additive identity (or zero element) of this ring? What is $A+\varnothing$?

Answer (score 0):

For 1, a unit is an element
that preserves the other operand.
Can you see an element
$u \in S$
such that
$u*A = A$ for every $A \in S$?

For 2,
can the intersection of two sets be empty
without either being empty?

For 3,
both $+$ and $*$ are binary operations.
Which operation do you want to
take the inverse with respect to?
From the answer to 1,
you have a unit $u$
for $*$.
The inverse $A^{-1}$ of
$A \in S$
satisfies
$A*A^{-1} = u$.
Can you find
$A^{-1}$ in terms of $A$.
What would such an inverse *mean*?